# Best way to use JavaScript in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

What is the best way to import and use JavaScript code in HTML pages? I am considering two options:

- Have single `<script>` tag with `all.js` file that is imported to HTML files, that uses selected JavaScript methods.
- Define separate `<script>` tag in each HTML file separately.

What is the best design option here?

Comment: Well minify javascript and use it accordingly it will help :)

Comment: Work out how you would do this with HTML and you have the answer.  It is the same for JSP, PHP, ASP..

Answer (score 4):

Lukasz, this innocent question is a big topic. To get started with JavaScript performance and maintainability in a nice place, follow [Steve Souders' writings](http://stevesouders.com/) on this.

And use [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/). That's much easier if your code is in a JavaScript-only file. To find out about other good practices, read [idiomatic.js](https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/).

Answer (score 1):

A single minified file is the most performant - less requests and smaller download. But not  one global js for everywhere, that would be a pain to debug/develop.

Use a cdn for libraries as probably cached in browser.

Answer (score 0):

IMO I will have separate tags for separate javascript snippets/plugins, it will make my javascript code easier to maintain. I can remove the plugin/add the plugin without disturbing the other javascript snippets.

But for performance issue, modern browsers will run 6 consecutive threads to download the resources, so it will be good idea to profile the loading times of the site/web app. You can use tools like Firebug/yslow to profile http requests being sent from the html page.

Personally I use template engines like [Sitemesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh/Home) and create templates for jsps for different parts of the application.

And for javascript I mainly use JQuery and a lot of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Minify js is a good and acceptable way. it also helps to build js files on the server side at run time. This is a big topic. Here are some good advices from yahoo. I use these as my guidlines. Also read on the topic js minify
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html